# If one random variable has lower variance than another, does its derivative have lower variance?

Tags: variance, random-variable, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be the probability triple.
Let $X: \Omega \times \Theta \to \mathcal X$ be a family of random variables, parametrized by $\theta \in \Theta$.
In other words, $X(\cdot, \theta): \mathcal \Omega \to \mathcal X$ is a random variable.
Similarly, let $Y: \Omega \times \Theta \to \mathcal Y$ be a family of random variables, also parametrized by $\theta \in \Theta$.

Does
$$
\mathbb V(X(\cdot, \theta)) \leq \mathbb V(Y(\cdot, \theta)), \forall \theta \in \Theta
$$
imply that
$$
\mathbb V(X'(\cdot, \theta)) \leq \mathbb V(Y'(\cdot, \theta)), \forall \theta \in \Theta
$$
where
$$
X'(\omega, \theta) = \frac{\partial X}{\partial \theta}(\omega, \theta) \\
Y'(\omega, \theta) = \frac{\partial Y}{\partial \theta}(\omega, \theta)
$$
?

Comment: This question is pretty meaningless unless you have _some_ connection between how the $X$ and the $Y$ are related to $\theta$.

Comment: The connection is that the variance of $X(\cdot, \theta)$ is lower than that of $Y(\cdot, \theta)$ for all $\theta$. In any case, a counter-example to this implication would also be a valid answer -- i.e. coming up with the some connection between how the $X$ and the $Y$ are related to $\theta$ and then demonstrating that the implication does not hold.

Comment: Most random variables will not have derivatives at all, so the question needs much more focus to be meaningful. You need some sort of *random functions*,  such as Brownian motions, which does not have derivatives in any usual sense ---